# What is the difference between frequency and probability in statistics?

Tags: probability, statistics

[Relative frequency](https://stattrek.com/statistics/dictionary.aspx?definition=relative%20frequency) is defined as

> A frequency count is a measure of the number of times that an event
>   occurs.
>
> To compute relative frequency, one obtains a frequency count for the
>   total population and a frequency count for a subgroup of the
>   population. The relative frequency for the subgroup is:
>
> Relative frequency = Subgroup count / Total count

And  probability also have same formula. So does that mean probability is a special type of relative frequency?

Comment: IMV more the other way around. A certain portion, but not all of probability theory, can be reduced to relative frequency. Backwards relative frequency can be caught completely in probability theory.

Comment: @drhab what do you mean by "IMV"

Comment: @Idk "In My View", so according to my insights.

Comment: @drhab please elaborate your view in answer.

Comment: @Orientalem Especially the fact that I would rather not elaborate on the subject made me decide to restrict myself to a (subjective) comment, and not to answer.

Comment: @drhab so don't you want to check your believe? This happen to me many times. I think that I'm making [arbitrary subject][1] (maths) more arbitrary (adding my own view). But what can I even do? By only adding our thaughts to a subject, we can understand it! So why not share your thought.


  [1]: https://www.google.com/search?q=Albert%20Einstein%20quote%20on%20physical%20concept&tbm=isch&client=ms-android-oppo&prmd=insv&hl=en&ved=2ahUKEwjSwvn8y4nnAhVi5TgGHaWQDBUQBXoECAEQGg&biw=360&bih=636#imgrc=bG4OzZCp71wcVM

Answer (score 1):

They’re not quite the same. Probability can be thought of a limit of relative frequency, though. For example, toss a fair coin ten times, and your relative frequency of heads is unlikely to be exactly $\frac12$, the probability of getting heads; rather, the probability of heads is the limit of the relative frequency as the number of tosses tends to infinity.